# I was dumb enough to fall for a phishing scam, and wondering does he have my codes in my Google Authenticator from my iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, hacking

So I believed a guy saying he was from Apple on the phone (so dumb of me) and he stole my AppleID and tricked me into creating a new one I then push everything to iCloud. He soon downloaded it onto his phone, change my AppleID password, and locked me out.  I lost a lot of stuff because of this. I was too slow to freeze all my assets, and he took a chunk. I changed all my passwords, but wondering does he have a copy of my Google Authenticator too.  And can gain access to my stuff again. If anyone can give me an answer it would be great because Apple says they don't know.

Comment: Oh dear - this sounds like quite the ordeal. Did you follow the playbook for detecting if your google account was compromised as well? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6294825?hl=en presumably that will get you control of the Authenticator and you can focus on the Apple side of things here.

Comment: thx for the reply. I did went to check the activity, everything seems normal and accounted for, but I am paranoid. Like will they be able to use my authenticator to change the passwords to my other apps.

Answer (score 1):

He should not be able to access your Google Authenticator codes given the scenario you have outlined.

Google Authenticator works completely offline, so while making sure that you have complete control over your Google Account is important, it won't give you control over the Authenticator as such.

Google Authenticator codes are not included in a non-encrypted backup, and they're not synced over iCloud. Therefore restoring such a non-encrypted backup from iTunes, or syncing another device with your iCloud account will not give the scammer access to your Authenticator codes.

Even having access to an encrypted backup or by restoring a new device from your stored iCloud backup should not give access to your codes. When you added them to your phone originally, they're stored in a way that is tied to that specific hardware device.

The only way to export the codes is to have the original device running, select the Export option and get the codes as QR-codes that can be scanned with a seperate device.

Comment: thx for the reply! I really appreciate it.  It gave me a peace of mind.